# How to get hostname rather opaqueref on xen with xmlrpc?

Tags: python, xml-rpc, xen

Using `xmlrpclib` from `Python2` it give back `OpaqueRef` but I would like to get more informations like the `status` of **all VMs** and their `names`, `bandwidth`, `VCPU`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import xmlrpclib
xen = xmlrpclib.Server('http://xen.server.address')
session = xen.session.login_with_password('user', '*****')['Value']
all_vms = xen.VM.get_all(session)['Value']
print(all_vms)
```

I have tried to works on the `status` part but do not find the way to print the status of all.

For one `VM` :

```
power_state = (records['OpaqueRef:***']['power_state'])
print 'KO' if power_state == 'Halted' else 'OK'
```

But get stuck on doing that for all `VMs` of the `Host`